# Add timestamp to each message in cognigy

Tags: javascript, html, css, time

I want to add timestamp below each message i.e user and bot message in cognigy.

```
const timePrint = async() => {
window.webchat = webchat;
webchat.registerAnalyticsService((event) => {
  if (event.type === 'webchat/incoming-message') {
    console.log("Testing input message");
    var time = new Date();       
    var curTime = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });
    console.log(curTime);
    let rowM = document.querySelectorAll('.webchat-message-row');
    rowM.forEach(el => {
        if(el.classList.contains('bot') && !el.classList.contains('old-message'))
        { 
          el.innerHTML += '<time class="incoming-time">'+curTime+'</time>'
        }
    })
  } 
  
  else if (event.type === 'webchat/outgoing-message') {
    console.log("Testing output message");
    var time = new Date();       
    var curTime = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });
    console.log(curTime);
    var rowM = document.querySelectorAll('.webchat-message-row');
    rowM.forEach(el => {
        if(el.classList.contains('user') && !el.classList.contains('old-message'))
        {
          el.innerHTML += '<time class="outgoing-time">'+curTime+'</time>'
        }
    })
  }
});};
```

I am using the above timePrint Function which fires itself whenever a incoming or outgoing event is trigerred and the time will be added to the both user and bot message. The problem is that console.log works perfectly fine but the time is not added to the bot or it gets added after 3 or 4 conversations.

Answer (score 0):

As in callback, you are changing `webchat`. So there is a possibility that messages will not be updated and saved properly.

But to make sure whether your timestamp has been saved and rendered successfully you should use some function to ensure the time delay so that it will stack that and also after every updation it will work efficiently.

For example, you might use a function like `setTimeOut` by providing some delay time to ensure the working.